# Debugging .NET / WP7 applications - should I write my own framework?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am currently developing for .NET and WP7, and I always run into the same problems. Little things like:

- Using wrong strings in databinding
- Forget to set visibility correctly
- Raise properties not at the right time

You get the idea, small stuff which is not essential but annoying. Especially when it comes to Windows Phone 7, because there you only got the small emulator, and can't just fire up a big windows to show the status of all your objects.

So my idea was the following:

- Use a basic helper classes which can e.g. list all properties
- Monitor list counts (empty list vs. data binding error)
- etc...

Now I need a way to monitor these objects in a "big window", my idea was to use WCF for that. Basically you have a MonitorService in your application which you can pass any objects (Services, ViewModels, etc) and which will transfer these objects (or their state) over the wire to a host application, showing a tree-like representation of you currently running application.

I already have logging which can be configured very nicely, but this is not really suitable for monitoring object states. So now my question is:

Are there any frameworks who e.g. hook into the monitoring and trace functionality of Visual Studio, and still allow to "design" the UI myself. Basically getting rid of the need for a WCF service to communicate between the running debug app and the "host window".

Any keywords for search are welcome, debugging and visual studio are not very google friendly :-)

Answer (score 1):

So how is the debugging functionality within VS not sufficient?